# How to get only the rows' indexes for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe `df1` of shape `(23,14)` and I create a dataframe `df2` with an array `mydata` of shape `(23,3)`.

I want the row index of `df2` to be the same as those of `df1`. How do I do it?

Here is what I tired:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = mydata, index = df1.index)
```

But I get the following error:

> Shape of passed values is (23, 3), indices imply (23, 14)

Answer (score 1):

pass numpy values:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = mydata.values, index = df1.index)
```

With your original attempt, you're passing the df as the data, so the ctor will try to reuse the df's existing index values, by passing a numpy array it becomes anonymous data.

When it reuses the df's indices, the result is effectively a reindex operation

You could also have done:

```
df2 = mydata.copy()
df2.index = df1.index
```

Comment: The *mydata* is an array (of shape (23,3)) so it does not have any attribute 'values'. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Please post raw data, your code and the desired output to avoid any ambiguity